# Cassandra read performance with Astyanax client

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra, astyanax, netflix

We are using `Cassandra database in production environment`. We have a `single cross colo cluster of 24 nodes` meaning `12 nodes in PHX` and `12 nodes in SLC colo`. We have a `replication factor of 4` which means `2 copies will be there in each datacenter`.

Below is the way by which `keyspace` and `column families` have been created by our `Production DBA's`.

> create keyspace profile with placement_strategy =
>   'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy' and
>   strategy_options = {slc:2,phx:2};
>
> ```
> create column family PROFILE_USER
> with key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
> and comparator = 'UTF8Type'
> and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
> and gc_grace = 86400;
> ```

We are running `Cassandra 1.2.2` and it has `org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner`, with `KeyCaching`, `SizeTieredCompactionStrategy` and `Virtual Nodes` enabled as well. **Cassandra nodes is deployed on `HDD instead of`SSD's`.**

I am using `Astyanax client` to read the data from `Cassandra database` using `consistency level as ONE`. I inserted `50 Millions records` (total around 285GB of data across 24 nodes) in the production cluster using the `Astyanax client` and after the compaction is finished, I started doing `read against the Cassandra production database`.

Below is the code by which I am creating connection configuration using `Astyanax client`-

```
/**
 * Creating Cassandra connection using Astyanax client
 *
 */
private CassandraAstyanaxConnection() {

    context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster(ModelConstants.CLUSTER)
    .forKeyspace(ModelConstants.KEYSPACE)
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
        .setPort(9160)
        .setMaxConnsPerHost(100)
        .setSeeds("cdb03.vip.phx.host.com:9160,cdb04.vip.phx.host.com:9160")
        .setLocalDatacenter("phx") //filtering out the nodes basis on data center
    )
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
        .setCqlVersion("3.0.0")
        .setTargetCassandraVersion("1.2")
        .setConnectionPoolType(ConnectionPoolType.ROUND_ROBIN)
        .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE))
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());

    context.start();
    keyspace = context.getEntity();

    emp_cf = ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily(
        ModelConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY, 
        StringSerializer.get(), 
        StringSerializer.get());
}
```

Most of the time I am getting `95th percentile read performance` around `8/9/10 ms`.

**I am trying to see is there any way I can get much better `read performance` with `Cassandra database`.** I was in the impression that I will be getting 95th percentile as `1 or 2 ms` but after doing some tests on the production cluster all my hypothesis went wrong. Ping time to Cassandra production nodes from where I am running my client program is `0.3ms average`.

Below is the result I am getting.

```
Read Latency(95th Percentile)      Number of Threads    Duration the program was running(in minutes)    Throughput(requests/seconds)    Total number of id's requested    Total number of columns requested
    8 milliseconds                         10                      30                                               1584                              2851481                        52764072
```

Can anyone shed some light on what other things I can try it out to achieve good read latency performance? I know there might be similar people in my same situation as well who are using Cassandra in production. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following:

### Astyanax

Set the ConnectionPoolType to TOKEN_AWARE instead of ROUND_ROBIN.

Additionally, I'd use some of the Astyanax latency aware connection pool features. For example:

```
.withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
        .setPort(9160)
        .setMaxConnsPerHost(100)
        .setSeeds("cdb03.vip.phx.host.com:9160,cdb04.vip.phx.host.com:9160")
        .setLocalDatacenter("phx") //filtering out the nodes basis on data center
        .setLatencyScoreStrategy(new SmaLatencyScoreStrategyImpl(10000,10000,100,0.50))
    )
```

The latency setting are provided via the constructor of the ScoreStrategy.  e.g. [SmaLatencyScoreStrategyImpl](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/astyanax-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/astyanax/connectionpool/impl/SmaLatencyScoreStrategyImpl.java#L16).

I am in the process of figuring this out as well, so I'll post back here if I learn anything additional.

See:  [Latency and Token Aware configuration](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Configuration)

### Cassandra

You could do a couple of things to optimize reads.  Note: I have not tried these, but they are on my list of things to investigate (so I figured I'd share).

**Cache**

Enable the Key cache and Row cache.

KeyCache

```
bin/nodetool --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080 setcachecapacity MyKeyspace MyColumnFam 200001 0
```

RowCache

```
bin/nodetool --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080 setcachecapacity MyKeyspace MyColumnFam 0 200005
```

Then check the hit rates after banging on that node for a while with your app scenarios:

```
bin/nodetool --host 127.0.0.1  --port 8080 cfstats
```

**Consistency**

Consider Read Consistency to ONE
See [this on Data Consistency](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/dml/data_consistency) (this is DataStax docs but still relevant)

Consider lowering the read repair chance.

```
update column family MyColumnFam with read_repair_chance=.5
```

After lowering the read_repair_chance consider tweaking the replication factor to help with read performance (but this will kill writes as we'll be writing to more nodes).

```
create keyspace cache with replication_factor=XX;
```

**Disk**

Not sure if there is anything to be done here but thought I should include it.
Ensure optimal file system (e.g. ext4).  If you have a high replication factor we could optimize the disk around that (knowing that we'll get our durability from Cassandra).  i.e. what RAID level is best for our setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried setting the connection pooling type to TOKEN_AWARE as well and I was getting very bad performance if I compared to ROUND_ROBIN connection pool type. So I reverted back to ROUND_ROBIN Connection Pooling with RING DESCRIBE as NodeDiscovery. I have tried various combinations of CONNECTION POOLING type and Node Discovery.

Comment: And regarding your second suggestion. Are you sure `getLatencyAwareWindowSize()` is being used anywhere? I tried putting the breakpoint and it was not hitting that code. So I am not sure whether it has any importance in setting those extra properties.

Comment: I assumed it was based on casual observation.  That said, it wouldn't surprise me if it isn't getting used, as I've seen similar config settings (e.g. NodeDiscoveryType) in Astyanax be ignored when I expected otherwise.

Comment: The code I included doesn't work with the latest Astyanax (as you've discovered with the latencyWindowSize).  You have set the latency values directly in the constructor of the SMA or EMA LatencyScoreStrategy construtor.  e.g. poolConfig.setLatencyScoreStrategy(new SmaLatencyScoreStrategyImpl(10000,10000,100,0.50));  Fixed my example code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am just curious what version of Cassandra you are using in production and what is your cluster specification? Maybe by that I can find something to optimize the read performance. And also what settings you are using with Astyanax in production as well will help a lot to me? Thanks.

Comment: I think we are using 1.08.  And, luckily, we aren't in "Prod" yet.  We are testing and optimizing and, literally, figuring this out right now (and over the last month) in AWS... and hopefully we will have it all dialed in by the time we release to Prod.  I'll come back w/ more as we learn and get it configured for Prod, but it actually sounds like you are further along in the lifecycle (dev->qa->prod) than I.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it out first of all in our LnP environment. And Astyanax performance was really good. But as soon as we shifted to our production cluster, the performance of Cassandra with Astyanax got worse, meaning I am getting 95th percentile most of time as `8/9/10 ms`. The only difference I can think of is, in lnp cassandra cluster, it was of 4 node cluster with rf of 2 but production cassandra cluster is of 24 nodes with rf of 4.